# Debugging a plugin running in a Teamcity instance

Tags: java, plugins, teamcity

I want to know the best way to debug a plugin for Teamcity. My current approach is to run mvn package, upload the zip file to Teamcity and then restart the server. This takes too much time. I've read I can pass this parameter to the JVM "**-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5555**" but I don't understand how can I debug a plugin if its not compiled by maven and then uploaded to the server?

If I create a breakpoint in my java code locally, how does the Teamcity instance know it should use this new code with the breakpoint?

It would be very helpful to see a video about this or a detailed guide. I cannot find this question properly answered anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Which plugin do you want to debug? A Maven plugin e.g. `maven-surfire-plugin`?

Comment: For example, one plugin from here: [https://plugins.jetbrains.com/teamcity]. I download the code, compile it and would like to know how to debug it once it's on teamcity

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to debug a plugin remotely, but you still have to build it (locally or on your continuous integration server), upload it, and restart the server.

1. in general, follow [these instructions](https://jaketrent.com/post/debugging-remote-tomcat-intellij/) for remote debugging from IntelliJ IDEA
2. in IntelliJ, there is no combo labeled "Unnamed"; instead, there is a button with a down arrow near the top-right corner; clicking that opens the Run/Debug Configurations dialog; add a configuration
3. on your server, set up a global environment variable `$TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS` = "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005" as per [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+TeamCity+Server+Startup+Properties#ConfiguringTeamCityServerStartupProperties-JVMOptions) (slightly different than JakeTrent.com suggests above)
4. upload your latest plugin, restart TC
5. in IntelliJ, make sure the new config is selected in the down-arrow combo
6. set your breakpoint (Ctrl-F8)
7. click the "bug" button to start debugging
8. in the TC GUI, trigger a build (or whatever triggers the activity in your plugin)

Comment: This is great, very useful. I am able to debug the plugin now. It is very time consuming to upload the plugin and restart the server but I guess it is the only option. Could it be possible to have a plugin running forever, like a listener? So I don't have to trigger a build to run the plugin. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by listener. Some plugins I created are listeners, but that actually means they listen to the run-build events and kick in when you run a build. I guess it depends on what your plugin should do; what should trigger it? Please upvote/mark my answer as correct if it works for you. Thanks!